# Photoshop Smart Filters

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I was looking at some freebies from [Orman Clark](http://www.premiumpixels.com/) and i've figured out that he uses **Smart Filters** to Add Noise to Layers, instead of rasterizing them.

Example of what Orman uses:

[image: Orman example]

Now I have two questions:

1. Are Smart Filters the best way to add noise and other effects for webdesign purpose?
2. What's the best way to use this?

Answer (score 2):

Smart Filter are nondestructive and offers more image-editing flexibility you can adjust, remove, or hide Smart Filters.and yes smart filters is the best way if you want to edit again and again, and the best way to use it depends on your need(on what you want)
**To apply a Smart Filter to a regular layer, select the layer, and choose Filter > Convert For Smart Filters, and click OK.**

Choose a filter from the Filter menu. You can choose any filter, including third-party filters that support Smart Filters, except Extract, Liquify, Pattern Maker, and Vanishing Point.